# options, optionsText and optionsValue in knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, data-binding, internationalization

I am wondering how data-bind, options, optionsText and optionsValue are working here ?

```
<div class="header dropdown">
         <select data-bind=" value: locale.selected_locale,
           options: [{ value: 'en-CA', label: 'english'}, { value: 'fr-CA',label: 'french'}],
           optionsText: function (item) {return i18n(item.label);},
           optionsValue: 'value' "  class="auto">
         </select>
     </div>
```

> Here is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7cm4wcsq/9/) from google
>   Chrome's inspect element (Translation of english and french words take
>   place on clicking English and French in the actual website) for the
>   above code.

In the actual website it ([Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7cm4wcsq/9/)) is working in a way that if I click on English then the whole page gets translated in English and if I click on French then the whole page is displayed in French.

en-CA and fr-CA are the JS files having translation of English and French words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `options` are bound to (as I presume) an observable `locale.selected_locale`. As you can see in the optionsText: `i18n(item.label)` there is some kind of i18n module responsible for translating the text.

Therefore, I assume there is a code (ko.computed) responsible for changing the locales reactively as such:

```
ko.computed(function(){
    //pseudocode; this function will run everytime locale.selected_locale changes
    var lang = locale.selected_locale();
    i18n.setLang(lang); 
});
```

I hope this helps for understanding what is going on, and how the translation can work on that site you investigated.

As the options bindings are concerned, check out the [knockout.js documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html) for options binding. Basically:

The value selected in the options will be stored in `locale.selected_locale`. There are two available options, each is storing the locale identifier that is passed to a i18n module, as well as the key identifier for label translation. So, in `en-CA` file, under "english" there will be a translation of "English", whereas in `fr-CA` under the same key, "Anglais" will be stored. `optionsValue` specifies which property in the chosen item object is storing the actual value that eventually will be stored in `locale.selected_locale`.

Comment: Yeah I can see `locale.selected_locale()` in some of the javascript files. As this is my first time working with knockout so had some confusion. I was trying to understand this whole thing bcoz I wanted to do slightly different basis on this.

Comment: I have created a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9x1rpz2b/3/). Now If I click on `Setting` button, it gives either `English` or `French` so if I click on `English` it should do exactly same thing what is happening with if I select `English` in that drop down box in the above code and same with `French`? How can I achieve that? Idea is to do same thing what is being achieved in the above code (through dropdown) but with different layout. Clicking on english will translate everything to english, clicking on french will translate everything to french(as the code is already doing that).

Comment: The only confusion I have is how to fit the drop down code which is  indeed doing translation part into my jsfiddle code so that I can test it out on my website with the new layout. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @user5447339 What i18n library are you using?

Comment: That I am not sure so I have to figure this out. As I am very new to i18n as well. Is there anything I should look into our code which can tells us what i18n library we are using?

Comment: I think we are using knockout js library.

Comment: @user5447339 Knockout is not internatiponalization library. Take a look at http://i18next.com/ for instance. You want to include that library into your code and trigger its function with knockout.js

Comment: I see.. What I was trying to do is - if you see my question. everything works fine from that drop down list. If I select English, it translates whole page into English and then if I select French, it translates into French. That means code is already there which does that and it is getting triggered from the drop down. Now I want to use the same code and put it in the jsfiddle code that I shown you. Difference is there is no dropdown in the jsfiddle code so I believe code `optionsText` is doing everything.. How can I put that code in my jsfiddle one and then I can test it out.

Comment: @user5447339 check out if there is `ko.computed` for `locale.selected_locale` observable and what it is doing.